# json parsing with jq and convert to csv

Tags: json, csv, jq

I need to get some values from a json file with JQ. I need to get a csv (Time, Data.key, Lat, Lng, Qline)

Input:

```
{
   "Time":"14:16:23",
   "Data":{
      "101043":{
         "Lat":49,
         "Lng":15,
         "Qline":420
      },
      "101044":{
         "Lat":48,
         "Lng":15,
         "Qline":421
      }
   }
}
```

Example output of csv:

```
"14:16:23", 101043, 49, 15, 420
"14:16:23", 101044, 48, 15, 421
```

Thanks a lot.
I tried only to:

```
cat test.json | jq '.Data[] |[ .Lat, .Lng, .Qline  ] | @csv'
```

Comment: Okay so where's your attempt?

Comment: I end my attempt: cat test.json | jq '.Data[] |[ .Lat, .Lng, .Qline  ] | @csv' My problem is Data.key and repeat Time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{ Time } + (.Data | to_entries[] | { key: .key | tonumber } + .value)
    | [ .Time, .key, .Lat, .Lng, .Qline ]
    | @csv
```

Make sure you get the raw output by using the `-r` switch.

Comment: Jeff - Thanks for promoting the pipe-at-beginning-of-line-when-line-must-be-split style :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't involve the +'s.

```
{Time, Data: (.Data | to_entries)[]} 
| [.Time, (.Data.key | tonumber), .Data.value.Lat, .Data.value.Lng, .Data.value.Qline] 
| @csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.  If `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
jq -M -r '(.Data|keys[]) as $k | {Time,k:$k}+.Data[$k] | [.[]] | @csv' data.json
```

will produce

```
"14:16:23","101043",49,15,420
"14:16:23","101044",48,15,421
```